# 分散と平均を求めるプログラムを作成したいのですが、main関数の実装方法がよくわかりません

Tags: c

タイトルの通り、分散と平均を求めるC言語プログラムを実装したいのですが、main関数部分でエラーが出てしまいます。

エラーメッセージが何を言っているのかよくわからなかったので、聞いた次第です。
私のプログラムはどこが間違っていますか。また、どこを修正すれば期待している結果がコンパイルさせるのですか。
回答よろしくお願いします。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
ex1505.c: In function ‘main’:
ex1505.c:66:28: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘ave_var_double_array’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     ave_var_double_array(a,&ave,num,&var);
                            ^
ex1505.c:39:6: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘double *’
 void ave_var_double_array(double a[], int size, double *ave, double *var)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ex1505.c:66:33: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘ave_var_double_array’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     ave_var_double_array(a,&ave,num,&var);
                                 ^~~
ex1505.c:39:6: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 void ave_var_double_array(double a[], int size, double *ave, double *var)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**ソースコード**

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* 要素数sizeの実数配列aに順に入力する */

**void readDoubleArray(double a[], int size)**
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%d番目?",i=i+1);
        scanf("%lf" ,&a[i]);
    }
}

/* 要素数sizeの実数配列aを順に出力する */
void printDoubleArray(double a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%f ",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}


/* 実数xの2乗を返す */
double square(double x)
{
    
    return x*x;
    
}

/* 要素数sizeの実数配列aの平均を *ave に，分散を *var に格納する */
void ave_var_double_array(double a[], int size, double *ave, double *var)
{
    int i;
    double sum=0.0, dsum=0.0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        sum=sum+a[i]; 
       *ave=sum/size;
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        dsum=dsum+(a[i]-*ave)*(a[i]-*ave); 
       *var=dsum/size;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    double a[100], ave, var ;
    int num;
     
    printf("データ数? ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    readDoubleArray(a, num);
    printDoubleArray(a, num);
  
    ave_var_double_array(a,&ave,num,&var);

    
    printf("平均: %f, 分散: %f\n", ave, var);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ave_var_double_array`関数の２つ目と３つ目の引数の順が間違ったようです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。引数の順番が間違っていたそうなので、引数を逆にし、readDoubleArrayのprintf文を直したところきちんとコンパイルできました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

関数の定義部分と呼び出し部分とで型が一致していない、というエラーでしょう。
コメントでも指摘のある通り、引数を渡す順番が間違っているのではないでしょうか？

**定義:** (double, **int**, double, double)

```
void ave_var_double_array(double a[], int size, double *ave, double *var)
```

**呼び出し:** (double, double, **int**, double)

```
double a[100], ave, var ;
int num;

ave_var_double_array(a,&ave,num,&var);
```